# In my API response json contents are in commented format, how i can remove the /* (comment line) and use them dynamically in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

1. The response is in JSON format but lines are commented.
2. I want to use retrieve the key-value pair from the response dynamically and use in Jmeter

I am beginner to JMeter.

Comment: what's the content-type of the api response? in case it's just text, you can probably simply `JSON.parse()` the repy

Comment: How to use it in the JMeter, can you please put more light on this.

Comment: Add example of response

Comment: /*
{
“key”:”value”,
 “key1”:”value1”,
 “key2”:”value2”
}
*/

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the "commented" JSON
2. Put the following code in "Script" area:

   ```
   def before = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
   log.info('Before:' + before)
   def after = before.replaceAll('/\\*','').replaceAll('\\*/','')
   log.info('After: ' + after)

   prev.setResponseData(after.getBytes('UTF-8'))
   ```
3. Tick 'Cache compiled script if available' box
4. Run your test

Now you should have the data without comments, it will be suitable for using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

[image: JMeter Manipulate JSON Groovy]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)